# Can't ask questions - But only three minorly downvoted questions asked?

Tags: support, down-votes, asking-questions

I have only ever asked six or seven questions, but three of them were "unclear" (although I thought them clear enough) and got downvoted once, with the exception of one being downvoted twice. That is a fairly low number. In the Help Center it says "One or two bad questions won't get you blocked". But three? Really? It's impeding my work progress on things I am required by deadline to get done.

Comment: You probably deleted some. Did you read the link you were provided?

Comment: It is a duplicate in some aspects, but what I'm getting at is the relatively low number of downvotes I got to get the block. Most people I've seen have 15-20 downvotes where I in total have four.

Comment: I'm sorry, what are you getting at, exactly, IHazABone? Are you proposing that the bar be changed?

Comment: I am proposing that it's strange that it blocked me so extremely quickly. And the only way is to positively contribute, but I am really inexperienced programming and I don't even understand 99% of the questions asked. So, am I stuck forever? Can't ever ask questions again until I have a few more years experience and actually understand things?

Comment: Not anymore it seems - I scooted over to your profile and it looks like you're getting upvotes on some of your questions again. The system has a pretty low threshold because the volume of crap we get is just too high to make any real compromises, but that's made up for by the fact that while it's indefinite, it's not permanent, but often salvageable.

Comment: That's a happening within the last 45 seconds. Did you do that...?

Comment: Nope - when I visited your profile the votes were already there. Apparently I missed it by 10 seconds.

Comment: Hai @IHazABone CanHazAskQuestion? IHazUpvotz KTHXBYE

Answer (score 4):

I upvoted one of your questions, and you're not blocked anymore.

**Your question quality must be better than the questions you've posted so far.  Carefully read the articles here: https://stackoverflow.com/help before asking your next question.**

You might also want to look at some other people's questions, and how they are being received by the community, to get a feel for what we expect here.

Comment: Thank you, but generally, what I'm getting downvoted for is the answer to my question is dead obvious to others whereas I am new and don't see it, or my formatting is bad, also an attribute of being a new programmer, or finally; I didn't use the correct terms when asking. All things that stem from me being 15 and inexperienced. I'm sorry.

Comment: Poor formatting was definitely an issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19058844/while-loop-continues-despite-conditions-not-being-met), @IHazABone, and your comment didn't help matters ("*I'm sorry, I cannot do that. I have very limited time right now, trying to do it within Stack Overflow is nearly impossible, and copy-pasting screws it up anyways.*"), but the main problem there, IMO, was the lack of apparent debugging effort you put into the problem yourself. The community rewards effort.

Comment: I was at school at the time. I didn't have enough time to reformat the code. I, as well as my instructor, put some effort into debugging it but I erased all that as to avoid confusion when posting the question. No, that comment probably did not help, and I will refrain from such as that in the future.

Comment: @IHazABone We certainly understand time restrictions, but generally speaking, you should not be asking a question unless you are willing to put in the time to the question and that doesn't just mean typing it out, but also typing it out well and formatting it properly and following up on the post for the first 10-60 minutes (or longer).  A lot can happen and if you don't respond quickly to questions or clarification requests, they are just going to downvote and move on to the next post.

Comment: @IHazABone another way to phrase my previous comment is "you expect someone to put in the time/effort to provide a quality answer to your question, then we expect/demand the same level of effort & commitment from you".  SO is not an ask it and leave type site.